# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable is being shown even though the variable is int

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
def solution(l):
    if 1 in l:
        l.pop(l.index(1))
        k=[[min(l)]]
        l.pop(l.index(min(l)))
        for a in l:
            for index,i in enumerate(k):
                if a%i[0]==0:
                    k[index].append(a)
                else:
                    k.append(a)
        print(k)

solution([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

My output is

```
if a%i[0]==0:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is this error happening? i[0] is an integer. I even printed datatype of i[0] it says it is an integer.

solution(l) takes a list and makes a list of numbers that are divisible by smaller other numbers.For above list [1,2,3,4,5,6] i want a list [[2,4,6],[3,6],[5]]

Any help is appriciated

Comment: `a` is not subscriptable. And you are appending `a` to `k` while iterating `k`. So eventually you will hit a non-subscriptable `i`.

Comment: but i am not subscripting a

Comment: Can you please correct my code i'm confused

Comment: It is not quite clear what problem your `solution` is trying to solve, so you would have to elaborate.

Comment: I added the the purpose of solution() please see it

Comment: @HarshitGupta the result should be : `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6]]`? cuz you said `makes a list of numbers that are divisible by smaller other numbers`,

Answer (score 0):

your error is generated because you are appending to your lists of lists `k` an integer: `k[index].append(a)` on the first iteration so on the second iteration of your second inner `for`loop by using `i[0]` you are doing `int_type[0]`:

```
def solution(l):
    if 1 in l:
        l.pop(l.index(1))
        k=[[min(l)]]
        l.pop(l.index(min(l)))
        for e1, a in enumerate(l):
            for index,i in enumerate(k):
                print('outer loop ', e1, ' inner loop ', index)
                print('k = ', k)
                print('i = ', i)
                if a % i[0] == 0:
                    k[index].append(a)
                else:
                    k.append(a)
        print(k)

solution([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

output:

```
outer loop  0  inner loop  0
k =  [[2]]
i =  [2]
outer loop  0  inner loop  1
k =  [[2], 3]
i =  3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-5da45c05c964> in <module>
     15         print(k)
     16 
---> 17 solution([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

<ipython-input-51-5da45c05c964> in solution(l)
      9                 print('k = ', k)
     10                 print('i = ', i)
---> 11                 if a % i[0] == 0:
     12                     k[index].append(a)
     13                 else:

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

The way you are using the inner `for` loop is not how you should do it, appending elements to your list while you are iterating may give you unexpected behavior like forever iterating and crush your program

---

> solution(l) takes a list and makes a list of numbers that are
>   divisible by smaller other numbers

```
def solution(l):
    return [[e for e in l if i%e==0] for i in l]

solution([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

# [[1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6]]
```